# How to install rabbitmq on Amazon Linux?

Tags: linux, erlang, rabbitmq, amazon-linux

I am trying to install rabbitmq on Amazon Linux. It has `Erlang R14B04` already installed. But rabbitmq gives error while installing from downloaded rpm package.

`Requires: erlang >= R16B-03`

So I installed `Erlang R16B03` from [repo](https://github.com/rabbitmq/erlang-rpm) provided by rabbitmq.
This is located at `usr/local/bin/erl` and system erlang is at `usr/bin/erl`.

When I install rabbitmq from downloaded rpm package by executing

`sudo yum install rabbitmq-server-3.6.9-1.el6.noarch.rpm`
It automatically uses `usr/bin/erl`. Is there any way I could force it to use `usr/local/bin/erl`?

I am following the [official documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html) for rabbitmq.

Answer (score 0):

sudo yum install erlang --enablerepo=epel

wget http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v3.1.1/rabbitmq-server-3.1.1-1.noarch.rpm

sudo rpm -Uvh rabbitmq-server-3.1.1-1.noarch.rpm

## Enable managament plugin

sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management